# Convert Date Milliseconds to Valid DateTime React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert the Milliseconds date from Server to valid datetime but for some reason the code is not working on react native as expected on my other applications

```
const ToValidDateTime = (date: string) => {
    console.log(date); //HERE Date Returned by server is ( /Date(1617048540000)/ )
    date = date.replace(/\D/g, ''); //removing everything just taking digits
    var fullDate = new Date(date); 
    console.log(fullDate); //here is just giving me Date { NaN }
    var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + 1 + "";
    if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1) twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
    var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
    if (twoDigitDate.length == 1) twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
    var currentDate =
        twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
    return currentDate;
}
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try this - `var fullDate = new Date(+date); `   You are passing a milliseconds value as a string but it should be a number passed to new Date()

Comment: Perfect man sorry missed that ! thanks ! it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert String to Number when you extract it from `/Date(1617048540000)/`

This should work

`var fullDate = new Date(Number(date));`

```js
var date = "Date(1617048540000)"
console.log(date); //HERE Date Returned by server is ( /Date(1617048540000)/ )
date = date.replace(/\D/g, ''); //removing everything just taking digits

console.log(date)
var fullDate = new Date(Number(date));

console.log(fullDate.toDateString()); //here is just giving me Date { NaN }

var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth() + 1 + "";
if (twoDigitMonth.length == 1) twoDigitMonth = "0" + twoDigitMonth;
var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate() + "";
if (twoDigitDate.length == 1) twoDigitDate = "0" + twoDigitDate;
var currentDate =
  twoDigitMonth + "/" + twoDigitDate + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
```